# How to make an outlook reminder popup and stay on top of other windows

Tags: vba, outlook, focus, reminders

How do you make an outlook reminder popup and stay on top of other windows?

After looking online for a long while; I wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer to this question.

Using Windows 7 and Microsoft Outlook 2007+; when a reminder flashes up, it no longer gives a modal box to grab your attention. At work where additional plugins can be problematic to install (admin rights) and when using a quiet system, meeting requests are often overlooked.

Is there an easier way to implement this ***without*** using third party plugins/apps?

> Sep 2021: Updated question title to indicate modal popup

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ***For the latest macro please see update 4 (Office 365 inclusion)***

After searching for a while I found a partial answer on a website that seemed to give me the majority of the solution;
https://superuser.com/questions/251963/how-to-make-outlook-calendar-reminders-stay-on-top-in-windows-7

However as noted in the comments, the first reminder failed to popup; while further reminders then did. based on the code I assumed this was because the window wasn't detected until it had instantiated once

To get around this, I looked to employ a timer to periodically test if the window was present and if it was, then bring it to the front.
Taking the code from the following website; [Outlook VBA - Run a code every half an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour)

Then melding the two solutions together gave a working solution to this problem.

From the trust centre, I enabled the use of macros then opening the visual basic editor from Outlook (alt+F11) I added the following code to the 'ThisOutlookSession' module

> CODE REMOVED

---

> ***UPDATE 1*** *(Feb 12, 2015)*

After using this for a while I found a real annoyance with the fact that triggering the timer removes the focus from the current window. It's a massive hassle as you're writing an e-mail.

As such I upgraded the code so that the timer only runs every 60 seconds then upon finding the first active reminder, the timer is stopped and the secondary event function is then used forthwith to activate the window focus change.

---

> ***UPDATE 2*** *(Sep 4, 2015)*

Having transitioned to Outlook 2013 - this code stopped working for me. I have now updated it with a further function (FindReminderWindow) that looks for a range of popup reminder captions. This now works for me in 2013 and should work for versions below 2013.

The FindReminderWindow function takes a value which is the number of iterations to step through to find the window. If you routinely have a larger number of reminders than 10 popup then you could increase this number in the EventMacro sub...

> CODE REMOVED

---

> ***UPDATE 3*** *(Aug 8, 2016)*

Having rethought my approach and based on observation - I redesigned the code to try and have a minimal impact on working while Outlook was open; I would find the timer still took focus away from e-mails I was writing and possibly other issues with windows losing focus might have been related.

Instead - I assumed the reminders window once instantiated was merely hidden and not destroyed when reminders were shown; as such I now keep a global handle to the window so I should only need to look once at the window titles and subsequently check if the reminders window is visible before making it modal.

Also - the timer is now only employed when the reminders window is triggered, then turned off once the function has run; hopefully stopping any intrusive macro's running during the working day.

See which one works for you I guess...

Updated code below:
Add the following code to the 'ThisOutlookSession' module

```
Private WithEvents MyReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyReminders = Outlook.Application.Reminders
End Sub

Private Sub MyReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call ActivateTimer(1)
End Sub
```

Then the updated module code...

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerfunc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName _
    As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
    ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1

Public TimerID As Long 'Need a timer ID to turn off the timer. If the timer ID <> 0 then the timer is running
Public hRemWnd As Long 'Store the handle of the reminder window

Public Sub ActivateTimer(ByVal Seconds As Long) 'The SetTimer call accepts milliseconds
    On Error Resume Next
    If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer   'Check to see if timer is running before call to SetTimer
    If TimerID = 0 Then TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, Seconds * 1000, AddressOf TriggerEvent)
End Sub

Public Sub DeactivateTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Success As Long: Success = KillTimer(0, TimerID)
    If Success <> 0 Then TimerID = 0
End Sub

Public Sub TriggerEvent(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)
    Call EventFunction
End Sub

Public Function EventFunction()
    On Error Resume Next
    If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer
    If hRemWnd = 0 Then hRemWnd = FindReminderWindow(100)
    If IsWindowVisible(hRemWnd) Then
        ShowWindow hRemWnd, 1                                   ' Activate Window
        SetWindowPos hRemWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS   ' Set Modal
    End If
End Function

Public Function FindReminderWindow(iUB As Integer) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
    FindReminderWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "1 Reminder")
    Do While i < iUB And FindReminderWindow = 0
        FindReminderWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, i & " Reminder(s)")
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    If FindReminderWindow <> 0 Then ShowWindow FindReminderWindow, 1
End Function
```

---

> ***UPDATE 4*** *(Sep 9, 2021)*

Transition to Office 365: This comes with an option in the settings now to show reminders on top of windows (picture below), so why would you want to run a macro to place it on top now? The reason is that you can set it as a modal reminder box (using SWP_DRAWFRAME) so if you swap between programs, it will stay visible which doesn't happen with the vanilla option

> Code *should* be compatible with all Outlook versions and allow transition between them easily (however I can no longer error check the non-VBA7 code)

[image]

> In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private WithEvents MyReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Outlook.Application
        Set MyReminders = .Reminders
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub MyReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call ReminderStartTimer
End Sub
```

> In a module

```
Option Explicit
' https://jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp; useful resource for Declare functions

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1, SWP_NOMOVE = &H2, SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10, SWP_DRAWFRAME = &H20, HWND_TOPMOST = -1, GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_DRAWFRAME

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Boolean
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Boolean
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, _
        ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
        ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, _
        ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
        ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    'TimerIDs to turn off timers. If a TimerID <> 0 then the timer is running
    Public ReminderTimerID As LongPtr
    
    Public Function ReminderStartTimer()
        On Error Resume Next
        Call ActivateTimer(1, AddressOf ReminderEvent, ReminderTimerID)
    End Function
    
    Public Sub ReminderEvent(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As LongPtr, ByVal idevent As LongPtr, ByVal Systime As LongPtr)
        On Error Resume Next
        Call EventFunction
    End Sub
    
    Private Function EventFunction()
        On Error Resume Next
        If ReminderTimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer(ReminderTimerID)
        Dim hRemWnd As LongPtr: FindWindowFromPartialCaption hRemWnd, "Reminder"
        If IsWindowVisible(hRemWnd) Then
            'ShowWindow hRemWnd, 1                                   ' Activate Window
            SetWindowPos hRemWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS   ' Set Modal
        End If
        Debug.Print TimeInMS() & "; " & hRemWnd
    End Function
    
    Private Function FindWindowFromPartialCaption(ByRef hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal PartialCaption As String)
        Dim hWndP As LongPtr: hWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'Parent Window
        Do While hWndP <> 0
            If InStr(GetNameFromHwnd(hWndP), PartialCaption) > 0 Then hWnd = hWndP
            If hWnd = hWndP Then Exit Do
            hWndP = GetWindow(hWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Loop
    End Function
    
    Private Function GetNameFromHwnd(ByRef hWnd As LongPtr) As String
        Dim Title As String * 255
        GetWindowText hWnd, Title, 255
        GetNameFromHwnd = Left(Title, GetWindowTextLength(hWnd))
    End Function

    Private Function ActivateTimer(ByVal Seconds As Long, FunctionAddress As LongLong, ByRef TimerID As LongPtr) 'The SetTimer call accepts milliseconds
        On Error Resume Next
        If TimerID = 0 Then TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, Seconds * 1000, FunctionAddress) 'Check to see if timer is running before call to SetTimer
    End Function
    
    Private Function DeactivateTimer(ByRef TimerID As LongLong)
        On Error Resume Next
        If KillTimer(0&, TimerID) <> 0 Then TimerID = 0
    End Function
#Else
    'TimerIDs to turn off timers. If a TimerID <> 0 then the timer is running
    Public ReminderTimerID As Long
    
    Public Function ReminderStartTimer()
        On Error Resume Next
        Call ActivateTimer(1, AddressOf ReminderEvent, ReminderTimerID)
    End Function

    Public Sub ReminderEvent(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)
        Call EventFunction
    End Sub
    
    Private Function ActivateTimer(ByVal Seconds As Long, FunctionAddress As Long, ByRef TimerID As Long) 'The SetTimer call accepts milliseconds
        On Error Resume Next
        If TimerID = 0 Then TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, Seconds * 1000, FunctionAddress) 'Check to see if timer is running before call to SetTimer
    End Function
    
    Private Function DeactivateTimer(ByRef TimerID As Long)
        On Error Resume Next
        If KillTimer(0, TimerID) <> 0 Then TimerID = 0
    End Function
    
    Private Function EventFunction()
        On Error Resume Next
        If ReminderTimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer(ReminderTimerID)
        Dim hRemWnd As Long: FindWindowFromPartialCaption hRemWnd, "Reminder"
        If IsWindowVisible(hRemWnd) Then
            'ShowWindow hRemWnd, 1                                   ' Activate Window
            SetWindowPos hRemWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS   ' Set Modal
        End If
        Debug.Print TimeInMS() & "; " & hRemWnd
    End Function
    
    Private Function FindWindowFromPartialCaption(ByRef hWnd As Long, ByVal PartialCaption As String)
        Dim hWndP As Long: hWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'Parent Window
        Do While hWndP <> 0
            If InStr(GetNameFromHwnd(hWndP), PartialCaption) > 0 Then hWnd = hWndP
            If hWnd = hWndP Then Exit Do
            hWndP = GetWindow(hWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Loop
    End Function
    
    Private Function GetNameFromHwnd(ByRef hWnd As Long) As String
        Dim Title As String * 255
        GetWindowText hWnd, Title, 255
        GetNameFromHwnd = Left(Title, GetWindowTextLength(hWnd))
    End Function
#End If

Private Function TimeInMS() As String
    Dim TimeNow As Double: TimeNow = Timer
    TimeInMS = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy ") & Format(DateAdd("s", TimeNow, 0), "hh:mm:ss.") & Right(Format(TimeNow, "#0.00"), 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your patient updates on this annoying bug that reappears when it's least expected...

Comment: Hi, is there a simple way to keep the reminder window on top?  It appears on top but goes to the background if you focus on another window.  Other than that this works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what your issue would be; when I use this code, the reminder stays on top when I focus on other windows...

Comment: Hi, when I restarted Outlook today it worked as expected by remaining on top.  Thank you great solution!

Comment: This is great, but with Outlook 2016, I am getting an error for the line
Private WithEvents MyReminders As Outlook.Reminders

Comment: I currently use this with Outlook 2016 with no issues: I can only suggest that maybe a reference needs to be added in the VB Editor? I would suggest checking that the Microsoft Outlook and Office Object Libraries are selected... Otherwise I'm not sure what the problem would be.

Comment: I have been using the code from Update 3 on Outlook 2016 and don't believe the assumption about the window handle is correct. I came to this conclusion after a few times that an email that I had opened in a separate window (instead of just in the reading pane) get stuck on top of all other windows. After I changed the code to always call FindReminderWindow I no longer saw the issue.

Comment: I have also seen that when my screen is locked the reminder window doesn't always end up as modal. I haven't found a fix that always works for that yet.

Comment: A minor change allows the window to be on top without stealing focus. 
Add this line:
Private Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
and change this line: 
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOACTIVATE

as found here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?558277-RESOLVED-Stay-On-Top-Don-t-Steal-Focus!

Comment: Snooze seems works, is there a way to pop up the reminder again at the exact appointment time?

Comment: @csrowell: I'm using the latest macros in this answer, and for me the reminder does _not_ steal focus.  I'm using latest Win 10 with latest Outlook 2016.

Answer (score 14):

Using AutoHotKey you can set the window to be Always On Top without stealing focus of the current window.  (Tested with WIn10 / Outlook 2013)

```
TrayTip Script, Looking for Reminder window to put on top, , 16
SetTitleMatchMode  2 ; windows contains
loop {
  WinWait, Reminder(s), 
  WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, on, Reminder(s)
  WinRestore, Reminder(s)
  TrayTip Outlook Reminder, You have an outlook reminder open, , 16
  WinWaitClose, Reminder(s), ,30
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks - I removed the TrayTip lines since there's no need to show the tooltips.

Comment: I'm not an autohotkey expert, but isn't this tight loop cause some cpu overhead?

Comment: Great! It uses no discernible CPU time on my machine. The steps in short: install AutoHotkey, put the above script into a file with the .ahk extension, right click on it to compile it, and make it start automatically with Windows (shell:startup).

Comment: Thanks for this great snippet of code. It inspired me to transform it into a stand-alone app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52251871/602585

Comment: Excellent! I found that this doesn't need to run in a loop. Once the "AlwaysOnTop" is set, the property sticks to the Reminders window (unless of course outlook is restarted)

Comment: @Matthew what I like about the loop is I keep getting the system tray notification pop up and go away every 30s, which has helped at times when I didn't notice the reminder window itself (on ultrawide monitor, this is a very real concern).

Comment: I agree 100% @SiliconBadger. I actually went back to the loop for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a free program called [PinMe!](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3551) that will do exactly what I want. When your Outlook Reminder appears, right click on PinMe! in the system tray and select the Reminder window. This will place a lock icon next to the window. Go ahead Dismiss or Snooze your Reminder. The next time the reminder pops, it should appear in the front of every other window. This will work regardless of Outlook in the foreground or minimized.

Comment: It is a false positive. Try on VirusTotal. I only see 1 being a potential issue. I've been using it for many months without ill effects. We run McAfee here.

Comment: I like and found pinMe, I'm struggeling how to instruct it to always show the Reminder in the front when I restart my PC.

Comment: @Cilvic - Yeah, I haven't figured that out myself either. It'd likely have to be an enhancement to start upon Windows boot, and to remember your previous settings.

Answer (score 3):

After being inspired by [Eric Labashosky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35154133/602585), I took his concept a step further and created [the NotifyWhenMicrosoftOutlookReminderWindowIsOpen app](https://github.com/deadlydog/NotifyWhenMicrosoftOutlookReminderWindowIsOpen), which you can download for free. It is a small executable that can ensure the Outlook Reminders window appears on top of other windows, as well as has some other optional ways of alerting the user that the window has opened.

Comment: I have been using this for a few days now and it is doing excellent. It's something I can recommend to coworkers as the VBA macros have a much higher barrier to entry (and haven't been as reliable in my experience). Plus this does a whole lot more to alert the user than just bringing the reminder window to the top.

Comment: After using the VBA macros for years, I switched to deadlydog's app a few months ago, and the app is working great.  Much simpler than all the VBA macro stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have Office 2013 and Windows 8.1 Pro. Many macros I found weren't handling the variable nature of the title Outlook places on the Reminder dialog. When you have 1 reminder, the title is "1 Reminder(s)" etc. I created a simple windows forms application in VB.NET, which I load on startup and keep minimized to the system tray. There is a 60 Timer added to the form which triggers the active code. When there is more than 0 reminders, the dialog box will be set to topmost and moved to 0,0.

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Public Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Public Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
End Module

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim titleString As String = ""

        Dim nullHandle As New IntPtr
        Dim windowHandle As New IntPtr
        Dim titleLength As Long

        Try
            Do
                Dim sb As New StringBuilder
                sb.Capacity = 512
                Dim prevHandle As IntPtr = windowHandle
                windowHandle = FindWindowEx(nullHandle, prevHandle, "#32770", vbNullString)

                If windowHandle <> 0 And windowHandle <> nullHandle Then
                    titleLength = GetWindowText(windowHandle, sb, 256)

                    If titleLength > 0 Then
                        titleString = sb.ToString

                        Dim stringPos As Integer = InStr(titleString, "Reminde", CompareMethod.Text)

                        If stringPos Then
                            Dim reminderCount As Integer = Val(Mid(titleString, 1, 2))
                            If reminderCount > 0 Then
                                Dim baseWindow As IntPtr = -1 '-1 is the topmost position
                                SetWindowPos(windowHandle, baseWindow, 0, 0, 100, 100, &H41)
                            End If
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2016 now provides an option to "Show reminders on top of other windows".  Use *File > Options > Advanced*, and then use the checkbox in the Reminders section. See this [support.office.com page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-or-remove-reminders-7a992377-ca93-4ddd-a711-851ef3597925?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EABAAA=2016,_2013) for screenshot.  This option was added in [Version 1804](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-new-in-office-365-95c8d81d-08ba-42c1-914f-bca4603e1426) of Outlook 2016, released to the "monthly channel" on April 25, 2018.

This Outlook 2016 option puts the reminder on top of all apps only initially.   I like to **keep** the reminder on top until I explicitly dismiss, even if I click some other window.  To **keep** the reminder on top I highly recommend using [the app in @deadlydog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52251871/41191).  @Tragamor's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23949000/41191) on this question also works to keep on top, and I used it for years, but much more complicated compared to the app by @deadlydog.

Comment: IT DOESN'T WORK!  I have been impatiently awaiting this Office 365 update to be pushed out through my company.  I enabled the option in File > Options > Advanced > Reminders > Show reminders on top of other windows.  But the Reminder windows DO NOT appear on top.  Even my Outlook inbox appears on top of these reminders. I'm going to try the app @deadlydog created.  M$ needs to get their act together.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in different Outlook versions even if I tested it only on Outlook 2013.

Since I cannot test it in a localized English version, you may need to customize the code lines related to searching the reminders window even if, in my answer, I changed the related code lines in order to find the window in the English localized version.

Let me know if the macro works in your English Outlook version.

The user is free to minimize or close the reminders window in which cases, when a new or existing reminder fires, the reminders window will be topmost and not activated.

The reminders window title will be always updated reflecting the real number of visible reminders even without activating it.

In all cases the reminders window will never steal focus unless, obviously, the foreground window is the reminders window, that is unless the user has deliberately selected the reminders window.

This macro, other than making the reminders window topmost, will also select the most recent reminder in the reminder window itself, you can customize this behavior, please read the code in order to be able to do that.

The macro also flashes the reminders window when showing the window for the first time and whenever a new or existing reminder fires again.

You can customize how many times the window flashes or any other parameters related to it, it should be clear how to do that.

Paste the next code lines into the class module 'ThisOutlookSession':

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
                                                    ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FlashWindowEx Lib "user32" (FWInfo As FLASHWINFO) As Boolean

Private Const FLASHW_STOP = 0
Private Const FLASHW_CAPTION = 1
Private Const FLASHW_TRAY = 2
Private Const FLASHW_ALL = FLASHW_CAPTION Or FLASHW_TRAY
Private Const FLASHW_TIMER = 4
Private Const FLASHW_TIMERNOFG = 12

Private Type FLASHWINFO
    cbSize As Long
    hwnd As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    uCount As Long
    dwTimeout As Long
End Type

Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Private Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Private Const HWND_TOP = 0
Private Const HWND_BOTTOM = 1
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = 1
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = 2
Private Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = 16
Private Const SWP_DRAWFRAME = 32
Private Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 512
Private Const SWP_NOZORDER = 4
Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 64

Private Existing_reminders_window As Boolean

Private WithEvents Rmds As Reminders

Public Reminders_window As Long

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Existing_reminders_window = False Then
        Set Rmds = Application.Reminders
        'In order to create the reminders window
        ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShowRemindersWindow")
        Reminders_window = FindWindow("#32770", "0 Reminder(s)")
        If Reminders_window = 0 Then
            Reminders_window = FindWindow("#32770", "0 Reminder")
            If Reminders_window = 0 Then
                Reminders_window = FindWindow("#32770", "0 Reminder ")
            End If      
        End If
        'To prevent stealing focus in case Outlook was in the foreground
        ShowWindow Reminders_window, 0
        SetWindowPos Reminders_window, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOACTIVATE
        Existing_reminders_window = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Rmds_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim FWInfo As FLASHWINFO
    If Existing_reminders_window = True Then
        Cancel = True
        With FWInfo
             .cbSize = 20
             .hwnd = Reminders_window
             .dwFlags = FLASHW_CAPTION
             .uCount = 4
             .dwTimeout = 0
        End With
        'In case the reminders window was not the highest topmost. This will not work on Windows 10 if the task manager window is topmost, the task manager and some other system windows have special z position
        SetWindowPos Reminders_window, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOACTIVATE
        ShowWindow Reminders_window, 4
        Select_specific_reminder
        FlashWindowEx FWInfo
    End If
End Sub
```

Paste the next code lines into a new or existing standard module:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Const WM_CHAR = &H102
Private Const VK_HOME = &H24
Private Const VK_END = &H23
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101

Public Sub Select_specific_reminder()
    Dim Retval As Long
    Retval = EnumChildWindows(ThisOutlookSession.Reminders_window, AddressOf EnumChildProc, 0)
End Sub
Private Function EnumChildProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Dim Nome_classe As String
    Nome_classe = Space$(256)
    GetClassName hwnd, Nome_classe, 256
    If InStr(Nome_classe, "SysListView32") Then
    'You can customize the next code line in order to select a specific reminder
        SendMessage hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_HOME, ByVal 0&
    End If
    EnumChildProc = 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest Outlook has this feature inbuilt and the same is answered in https://superuser.com/a/1327856/913992

Comment: Thanks for the comments: the inbuilt feature is referenced by @netjeff in his comment for Outlook 2016 onwards. The link to the superuser answer is included as a resource in my original answer and as stated does not provide a full answer which is why there is further coding supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Just Alt F11 and copy paste this code..Works for me

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean

Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "User32" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32" ( _
ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim ReminderWindowHWnd As Variant
On Error Resume Next
  Dim lhWndP As Long
    If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, "Reminder") = True Then
        SetWindowPos lhWndP, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetHandleFromPartialCaption(ByRef lWnd As Long, ByVal sCaption As String) As Boolean

     Dim lhWndP As Long
        Dim sStr As String
        GetHandleFromPartialCaption = False
        lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
        Do While lhWndP <> 0
            sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
            GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
            sStr = Left$(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
            If InStr(1, sStr, sCaption) > 0 Then
                GetHandleFromPartialCaption = True
                lWnd = lhWndP
                Exit Do
            End If
            lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Loop
     End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it fails to pick up the first reminder fired after opening Outlook and does not set it on top. The link to the superuser answer is included as a resource in my original answer and contains similar code which also does not provide a full answer which is why there is further coding supplied