# (VBA on OUTLOOK) check if email has not been received vba

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I need one macro on Outlook  that do the logic below:

- Every workday between 9:00 am to 10:00am check in specific folder if have any email, from that day.
- If don't have email, send an simple mail to specific person.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> Every workday between 9:00 am to 10:00am check in specific folder if have any email, from that day.

You need to run a timer to run the task periodically. See [Outlook VBA - Run a code every half an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour) for more information. Use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the Items class to find Outlook items that correspond to your criteria.

> If don't have email, send an simple mail to specific person.

If there is no item found see #1, you can create and submit the mail item.

```
      ' Create the message.
      Set objOutlookMsg  = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

      With objOutlookMsg
          ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Nancy Davolio")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

          ' Add the CC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Michael Suyama")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olCC

         ' Add the BCC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Andrew Fuller")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olBCC

         ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
         .Subject = "This is an Automation test with Microsoft Outlook"
         .Body = "This is the body of the message." &vbCrLf & vbCrLf
         .Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance

         ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
         For Each ObjOutlookRecip In .Recipients
             objOutlookRecip.Resolve
         Next

        .Save
        .Send
      End With
```