# Macro to run outlook rule every 5 minutes

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a rule called "CategorizeMe" and I need it to run every 15 minutes.

Currently I have to click "Rules" then "Manage Rules" then "Run Rules Now"

So I need help with creating a VBA module or Macro to automatically run while Outlook is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a timer to be able to run the code periodically. See [Outlook VBA - Run a code every half an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour) for more information and sample code.

Comment: I saw this. How do I get "Private Sub Application_Quit()" or "Private Sub Application_Startup()"

Comment: They are event handlers in VBA. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .

Comment: I followed the instructions on that post and nothing happens.