# Error when Outlook VBA macro runs too frequently

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Let me start with a brief description of what my project accomplishes currently. I have 3 subroutines in 'ThisOutlookSession'. One checks the last ~30 unread mail items and sends the subject to a sub that checks it's contents for a key word, the other does the same thing but handling the Items_ItemAdd event (new incoming mail) and the last sub I alluded to already checks the subject line and if a keyword is found calls a module I named 'ExcelConnection' which is where the issue stems from.

In the 'ExcelConnection' module I have this code that opens a workbook:

```
Dim oXL As Object
Dim oWS As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Workbooks.Open FileName:="T:\Capstone Proj\TimeStampsOnly.xlsx", AddTOMRU:=False, UpdateLinks:=False

'// Change sheet name to suit
Set oWS = oXL.Sheets("TimeStamps")
```

**The issue is**: This process takes about a minute or so to complete and then it goes through an ExitSave point where the workbook is saved, closed, and the application 'quits', BUT if another piece of mail comes in before it finished running and "ExitSaving" it gives an error saying I cant open the workbook since it's already open. This also stops the initial instance and the result is the workbook stays open in the background where I can't close it manually and I cant edit it either since it keeps saying it's being modified by 'Another User' (Outlook).

Is there any way to tell the macro to wait until the everything is done running before it runs again? This only happens when two pieces of mail with keywords come in within a minute or so of each other.

If you have any questions or need more code samples please let me know! Thank you.

---

**Edit:**
This is the code for the 'ExcelConnection' module that is triggered by a keyword in subject line of email.

```
    Public Sub ExcelConnect(msg As Outlook.MailItem, LType As String)
'// Declare all variables needed for excel functionality and open appropriate document
    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWS As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long

Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oXL.Workbooks.Open FileName:="T:\Capstone Proj\TimeStampsOnly.xlsx", AddTOMRU:=False, UpdateLinks:=False

'// Change sheet name to suit
Set oWS = oXL.Sheets("TimeStamps")
lngRow = oWS.Range("A" & oXL.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Offset(1).Row '// -4162 = xlUp. not available late bound

Dim subArray() As String
Dim jRow As Long
Dim jobnum As Variant


subArray = Split(msg.Subject, "-", 2)   '// Need the hypen to end the standardized subject line
jobnum = Trim(Right(subArray(0), 8))
jRow = IsExist(jobnum, lngRow, oWS)


Select Case LType '// Choose actions based on proccess step

    Case "MDIQE"
    If oWS.cells(jRow, 3).Value <> 0 Then
    GoTo ExitSave
    Else
        With oWS
            .cells(jRow, 1).Value = jobnum
            .cells(jRow, 2).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
            .cells(jRow, 3).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
        End With
    End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------
        Case "MDIQ"
        If oWS.cells(jRow, 2).Value <> 0 Then
        GoTo ExitSave
        Else
            With oWS
                .cells(jRow, 1).Value = jobnum
                .cells(jRow, 2).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
            End With
        End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------
        Case "MDIE"
        If oWS.cells(jRow, 3).Value <> 0 Then
        GoTo ExitSave
        Else
            With oWS
                .cells(jRow, 1).Value = jobnum
                .cells(jRow, 3).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
            End With
        End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------
        Case "MDIR"
        If oWS.cells(jRow, 4).Value <> 0 Then
        GoTo ExitSave
        Else
            With oWS
                .cells(jRow, 1).Value = jobnum
                .cells(jRow, 4).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
            End With
        End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------
        Case "MDIP"
        If oWS.cells(jRow, 5).Value <> 0 Then
        GoTo ExitSave
        Else
            With oWS
                .cells(jRow, 1).Value = jobnum
                .cells(jRow, 5).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
            End With
        End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------
        Case "MDIF"
        If oWS.cells(jRow, 6).Value <> 0 Then
        GoTo ExitSave
        Else
            With oWS
                .cells(jRow, 1).Value = jobnum
                .cells(jRow, 6).Value = msg.ReceivedTime
            End With
        End If

    End Select

ExitSave:
    With oXL
        .activeworkbook.Save
        .activeworkbook.Close SaveChanges:=1   '// 2 = xlDoNotSaveChanges but not availabe late bound
        .Application.Quit
    End With

    Set oXL = Nothing
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub
Function IsExist(jobnum As Variant, upper As Long, oWS As Object) As Long
    Dim i As Integer, ValueToFind As Variant
    ValueToFind = jobnum
    For i = (upper - 1) To 1 Step -1
        If CStr(oWS.cells(i, 1).Value) = ValueToFind Then
            IsExist = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
IsExist = upper 'If found nothing
End Function
```

Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: Can you not just set Outlook to not check for new mail so often, in Options? ...or, set it programmatically to not check the mail at all when the sub starts, and change back at the end of the sub?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook VBA - Run a code every half an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour)

Comment: @ashleedawg I like the idea of having it not check for new mail until the sub is done/ExitSave procedure is finished. I believe that is the metaphorical 'pause' I am looking for. Do you have a link or code sample that handles that by chance?

Comment: I may have a suggestion but I need to undertsand as to what do you do after opening the workbook.

Comment: @SiddharthRout once the workbook is open I select a case based on which keyword was found in the subject and then insert a 'recievedtime' timestamp into an appropriate cell location. After the timestamp is entered I save, close, and quit excel. Issue is if more mail comes in before it saves and quits the workbook will be open still and the code will throw errors and leaves the workbook open.

Comment: If you do not mind, can you update the quesiton with the exact code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, sure I'll upload now

Comment: Thank you, Before I even suggest you what I have in my mind. Let me first try it out :D

Comment: Can you share what are the column headers for Col A - F?

Comment: Ok do not share but put it in the code that I posted below

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used manipulating Excel from Outlook, so this code will probably need some adjustment. The Sub `Main` will keep checking a specific workbook, until it's opened and not read-only. After doing code, it then closes the workbook and exits the loop. The only downside of this, is that the code will keep running until it has access to the workbook. You could add a counter to keep track of the number of attempts and exit once a specific number has been reached.

Functions `ExtractName` and `WorkbookIsOpen` are support functions included below `Main`.

```
Public Function Main(wbkLoc As String) As Boolean
    Dim wbk As Workbook

    Do While Not WorkbookIsOpen(ExtractName(wbkLoc)) Then
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(wbkLoc)

        'Will open read-only if shared file is already open on another computer
        If wbk.ReadOnly Then
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Else
            'ExcelConnection code
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Exit Do
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set wbk = Nothing
End Function

'Allows use of location variable in Main without hardcoding workbook name
Private Function ExtractName(longName As String) As String
    Dim lastDash As Integer
    Dim extension As Integer

    extension = InStr(1, StrReverse(longName), ".")
    lastDash = InStr(1, StrReverse(longName), "\")
    ExtractName = StrReverse(Mid(StrReverse(longName), extension + 1, lastDash - extension - 1))
End Function

' Returns true if workbook is already open on same computer
Private Function WorkbookIsOpen(rsWbkName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorkbookIsOpen = CBool(Len(Workbooks(rsWbkName).Name) > 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In outlook the minimum automatic send and receive can be set to 1 minute as shown below.

[image]

Yes if your process takes 1 minute or so then you can increase this to 5 mins or to whatever you want but this may not keep you updated with latest emails. Mine is set to **1 Minute**. You may call me paranoid **0_0**!

So when you are paranoid like me then what is the alternative? If there was a way which ran your code not in **1 minute or so** but in **1 second or so** then your problem should be solved. Right? :)

Use `OLEDB` to write to the Excel file. This code finds the job number and writes to that row if the relevant cell is empty and then saves the files in less than **2 seconds**

```
Const FName As String = "T:\Capstone Proj\TimeStampsOnly.xlsx"
Const SheetName As String = "TimeStamps"

Const adUseClient = 3
Const adOpenDynamic = 2
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Const Col_A As String = "Put Column A header here"
Const Col_B As String = "Put Column B header here"
Const Col_C As String = "Put Column C header here"
Const Col_D As String = "Put Column D header here"
Const Col_E As String = "Put Column E header here"
Const Col_F As String = "Put Column F header here"

Public Sub ExcelConnect(msg As Outlook.MailItem, LType As String)
    Dim ReceivedTime As String, jobnum As String
    Dim conString As String

    Dim objRecordset As Object, objConnection As Object

    ReceivedTime = msg.ReceivedTime
    jobnum = Trim(Right(Split(msg.Subject, "-", 2)(0), 8))

    conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
                FName & _
                ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConnection.Open conString

    objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [" & SheetName & "$] WHERE " & Col_A & " ='" & jobnum & "'", _
    objConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    If objRecordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
        With objRecordset
            Select Case LType
                Case "MDIQE"
                    If Len(Trim(.Fields.Item(Col_C).Value)) = 0 Then
                        .Fields.Item(Col_B).Value = ReceivedTime
                        .Fields.Item(Col_C).Value = ReceivedTime
                        .Update
                    End If
                Case "MDIQ"
                    If Len(Trim(.Fields.Item(Col_B).Value)) = 0 Then
                        .Fields.Item(Col_B).Value = ReceivedTime
                        .Update
                    End If
                Case "MDIE"
                    If Len(Trim(.Fields.Item(Col_C).Value)) = 0 Then
                        .Fields.Item(Col_C).Value = ReceivedTime
                        .Update
                    End If
                Case "MDIR"
                    If Len(Trim(.Fields.Item(Col_D).Value)) = 0 Then
                        .Fields.Item(Col_D).Value = ReceivedTime
                        .Update
                    End If
                Case "MDIP"
                    If Len(Trim(.Fields.Item(Col_E).Value)) = 0 Then
                        .Fields.Item(Col_E).Value = ReceivedTime
                        .Update
                    End If
                Case "MDIF"
                    If Len(Trim(.Fields.Item(Col_F).Value)) = 0 Then
                        .Fields.Item(Col_G).Value = ReceivedTime
                        .Update
                    End If
            End Select
        End With
    End If

    objConnection.Close
End Sub
```

The above code is tried and tested with my excel file. If you face any problem then let me know and we will try and fix it.

Comment: Hey thanks for this effort, I like the idea you have to try and shorten the process time, definitely something I thought of but didn't know what avenue to go down. So I'm debugging it now because it's throwing me an error. when this line runs `objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [" & SheetName & "$] WHERE " & Col_A & "='" & jobnum & "'", _
    objConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText` I get this in my error handler.  "  -2147217900 - Syntax error in date in query expression 'CRM #='2345678"  " where CRM # is the col name and 2345678 is the jobnum

Comment: Just fr testing purpose can you chnage the column heading to `CRM` instead of `CRM #`?

Comment: So I made some slight changes to your code, namely changing that line that was throwing an error to this `objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [" & SheetName & "$]", _
    objConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText` from my understanding your code looked for the record matching the jobnum, however there will be many cases where the jobnum doesnt exist yet and a new record will have to be created. So after that line I have your `if objrecordset.record count > 0` qualifier and an `objrecordset.find` that looks for a row with the jobnum. The line with the Len(Trim... returns empty now

Comment: And yes I can change the header to just CRM, which I did but was no longer the issue after the changes I made above. Btw, I ran out of space on the previous comment but the Len(Trim... line says expression is not defined in context so I'm not sure if I have to somehow select the record after I find it for it to know what field/item to look at or whats going on. I haven't used ADODB for VBA before this haha